# Vigenere Cypher - Code is not working as I expect

Tags: arrays, encryption, cs50, vigenere, sc

I'm trying to figure out why my code is not iterating correctly on z. I would like to iterate every 1 z, but it seems like it's a bit random. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do this? If there anything else I'm doing wrong, please let me know. I think I'm really close. I'm also curious how I block spaces/other characters from being encrypted.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int shift(char c);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
// Check to see if two arguments are enterted at launch 
int cipher = 0;
 if (argc != 2)
 {
    // If not return error & return 0
    printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword \n");
    return 1;
 }
 else
 {
    int strlength = strlen(argv[1]);
    // Iterates through characters in second argument (key), checking to see 
    if they are digits
    for (int k = 0; k < strlength; k++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][k]))
        {
            // If not return error & return 1
            printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
            return 2;
        }
     }
        //char *c =argv[1];
        string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
        int len = (int) strlen(plaintext);
        //int b = atoi(c);
        //char code[len];
        //strcpy (code, plaintext);
         int z=0;
         for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)   
         {

                int key = shift(argv[1][z]);
             //printf("%i",z);
              if (isupper(argv[1][z]))
                {
                  //printf("theory\n");
                  cipher = ((((plaintext[j] - 'A') + key) + 'A'));
                  //cipher = ((((plaintext[j] - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A');
                  //printf("%c", (((plaintext[j] - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A');
                 //printf("%i",z);


                  printf("%c",cipher);

                 }

                 if (islower(argv[1][z]))
                    {

                    //printf("theory\n");  
                    cipher = (((plaintext[j] - 'a') + key) + 'a');


                     //printf("%i",z);

                      printf("%c",cipher);  


                  }
                  //z++;     
                 //else if (!isalpha(plaintext[j]))
                    //{
                        //printf("%c", plaintext[j]);  
                     //}

                  if (z > strlen(argv[1])-1)
                 {
                          z=0;
                 }

                /* else 
                 {
                 z++;
                 }

                 else
                 {
                 z++;
                 }
                 */
                 //z++;
              }



            printf("\n");

             }
}
 int shift(char c)
 {
    int i = c;
    if (i <= 'Z' && i >= 'A')
    {
       return ((i - 'A') % 26);
    }
    else
    {
        return ((i - 'a') % 26);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO please, remove the unnecessary comments,  and please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is uncommented `if they are digits` that will prevent the compile! You should increment `z` or better  `int key = shift(argv[1][j % key_length]);`